# spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactiv and multi module

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, reactive

I have 2 small projects.
One "commons" project where are located 2 entities and 2 repositories like
fr.mycompany.commons.cassandra.entities:

For example, my first entity:

```
package fr.mycompany.commons.cassandra.entities;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;
@Data
@Builder
@Table("myfirstentity")
public class MyFirstEntity {
    ...
}
```

And under fr.mycompany.commons.cassandra.repositories:

```
package fr.mycompany.cassandra.repositories;
import fr.mycompany.commons.cassandra.entities.MyFirstEntity:
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.ReactiveCassandraRepository;

public interface MyFirstRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<MyFirstEntity, String> {
}
```

And Y have a second project like "loader" and my loader have a maven dependency on "commmons"

where I use in class

```
@Autowired private MyFirstRepository myFirstRepository;
```

But when I add the component scan on my spring boot application,
the application don't finish to start without any clue ...
example:

```
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters = false, basePackages = {"fr.mycompany.commons.cassandra.repositories", "fr.mycompany.commons.cassandra..entities"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have read in certains blogs, if we have two separated maven modules, you must specify the component scan ...
But I have tried several configuration like, with useDefaultFilters = false (and without attribute), only with basePackages = "fr.mycompany.commons"
but nothing really work ... and the simple log trace is:

```
2018-07-24 12:58:15,486 INFO [StartupInfoLogger.java:50] Starting Application on user1 with PID 10075 (/home/user1/Java/Workspaces/idea-workspace/loader/target/classes started by user1 in /home/user1/Java/Workspaces/idea-workspace/loader)
2018-07-24 12:58:15,494 DEBUG [StartupInfoLogger.java:53] Running with Spring Boot v2.0.1.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.5.RELEASE
2018-07-24 12:58:15,497 INFO [SpringApplication.java:659] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-24 12:58:18,713 INFO [StartupInfoLogger.java:59] Started Application in 3.603 seconds (JVM running for 4.386)
```

Does anyone have an idea?

thank and best regards,

Adrien

Comment: I had similar problem.  Adding @EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages in Startup solved for me.